# How do I include a single-quote in MSBuild item transformation seperator?

Tags: msbuild

I need to include a single quote in an item transformation, like so:

```
<DatabaseFileNames>@(DatabaseFiles->'%(PhysicalName)', '','')</DatabaseFileNames>
```

This, however, spits out a rather cryptic error:

> error MSB4095: The item metadata
>   %(PhysicalName) is being referenced
>   without an item name.  Specify the
>   item name by using
>   %(itemname. PhysicalName).

I'm basically trying to create a comma-seperated list of single-quoted values.

How do I get single-quotes into the transformation seperator?

I tried using HTML-entities (the entity for single quote is &#39;), like so:

```
<DatabaseFileNames>@(DatabaseFiles->'%(PhysicalName)', '&#39;,&#39;')</DatabaseFileNames>
```

But I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have to use URL-encoding style escapes, that is, %CharacterHexNumber.  In this case, the single quote is ASCII character 39, which is 27 in hex, so the correct escape sequence is:

```
<DatabaseFileNames>@(DatabaseFiles->'%(PhysicalName)', '%27,%27')</DatabaseFileNames>
```